# canActive angular how can I get value true false from auth (user login or not)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how can I check if user log in or not, I use this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.subscribeLogger().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.checkUserLogin = data;
      }
    );
  }
```

for getting value true or false, but I cant console log it, I know it wrong but how can I get value if user login or not from authservice??

This is the file `history.guard.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'app/core/service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HistoryGuard implements CanActivate {
  checkUserLogin: boolean;
  constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private auth: AuthService,
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.subscribeLogger().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.checkUserLogin = data;
      }
    );
  }

  canActivate() {
    if(this.checkUserLogin){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return this.router.navigate(['mypage']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do I need to write some code in AuthService to subscribe ?

Answer (score 1):

CanActivate can return an Observable.

have not tested, but something like this should work:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private auth: AuthService){}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routeState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    return this.auth.subscribeLogger().pipe(
      map(isUserLoggedin => {
          if (!isUserLoggedin) {
            this.router.navigate(['mypage']);
          }
          return isUserLoggedin; 
      });
}
```

Comment: I change  Observable<boolean|UrlTree> to  Observable<any> but not work :(

Comment: value still be false not true after I put JWT_TOKEN in.

Comment: well, please add `console.log(isUserLoggedIn)` one line above `if (!isUserLoggedIn) ...` whats the output ?

Comment: always false ! because this subscribeLogger I set it false in auservice!

Comment: do I need to create new func in auth.service.ts because subscribeLogger always return false??

Comment: this is subscribeLogger in auth.service.ts    `export class AuthService {logger = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(false);}`                                                                      `subscribeLogger(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.logger.asObservable();
  }` @Stavm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this way by using async await

```
async canActivate() {
    const isAuthenticate = await this.auth.subscribeLogger();
    if(!isAuthenticate){
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return this.router.navigate(['mypage']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: it's still get false value! I tested with no JWT_TOKEN (false), then have JWT (still false)

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnInit`should be implemented in directives or components. You can try getting rid of it from your class and modify the logic inside `canActivate` as below:

```
canActivate() {
    this.auth.subscribeLogger().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        if(data) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return this.router.navigate(['mypage']);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: it didnt work :( even I put :any after canActivate()

Comment: I tried to reproduce the scenario keeping it very basic. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-87mquv. And @Stavm 's answer is more promising.

Comment: I got it, but I still misunderstand how can I get auth value in my case

Comment: I suppose your `this.auth.subscribeLogger ` is not returning a value

Comment: it always returns value "false"  use can go this link for full code [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57091508/guard-in-angular-how-can-i-get-value-from-auth-service-ts-user-login-or-not]